# How do I get deep nesting of data in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to get a nested data structure in a single query, but when using one-to-one, the data is lost.

Data model:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const Organization = sequelize.define('organization', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const Bank = sequelize.define('bank', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const Tax = sequelize.define('tax', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const BankDescription = sequelize.define('bankDescription', { description: DataTypes.STRING });
 
User.belongsTo(Organization);
Organization.hasMany(User);
Organization.hasOne(Bank);
Bank.belongsTo(Organization);
Bank.belongsTo(Tax);
Bank.hasOne(BankDescription);
BankDescription.belongsTo(Bank);
```

Building a query with include associations:

```
const user = await User.findByPk(id, {
      include: [
        {
          association: Organization,
          include: [
            {
              association: Bank,
              include: [
                { association: Tax },
                { association: BankDescription},
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
})
```

Output:

```
{
    name: 'Don',
    organization: {
    name: 'MZZ',
    bank: {},
  },
}
```

But `await user.organization.bank.getBankDescription()` and `await user.organization.bank.getTax()` return data.

If query will be:

```
const user = await User.findByPk(id, {
      include: [
        {
          association: Organization,
          include: [
            {
              association: Bank,
              include: [
                { association: Tax },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
})
```

Output will be:

```
{
    name: 'Don',
    organization: {
    name: 'MZZ',
    bank: {
      tax: {
        name: 'fix'
     }
   },
  },
}
```

Why is this happening?
Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are not using the correct syntax. The `include` property should be either an object or an array of objects. For each included Model you should use the `model` property and if you need to specify a particular relationship, the `as` property. If you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` for the relationships (so that they are not required to return results for the `User` then you should also specify `required: false`.

```js
const user = await User.findByPk(id, {
  // this include could be an object instead of an array
  include: {
    // use `model` to specify the model
    model: Organization,
    include: {
      model: Bank,
      // if you wanted to specify a particular association use the same `as` property
      /* as: 'bank', */
      include: [
        // make Tax optional with a LEFT JOIN via required: false
        { model: Tax, required: false },
        // without required this is a JOIN, so BankDescription is required
        { model: BankDescription },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it don't work .
For my example, I don't get the attribute "name" in Bank. If you remove the `{ model: BankDescription }` I get the attributes of Bank and Tax.